# When updating a row, how to also keep the old values and update the linking tables?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

I have two tables; `ItemTable` and `ProductTable`. `ProductTable`'s `ItemID` column links to `ItemTable`'s `ID` column. The `ID` columns of both tables are primary keys and identity columns.

Like this:

```sql
ItemTable:

ID    Col      ColOther    Latest    Time
100   'old'    'oldother'  1         <Autogenerated timestamp>


ProductTable:

ID    ItemID   Value   ValueOther   Latest   Time
12    100      'foo'   'bar'        1        <Autogenerated timestamp>
```

Whenever I want to **manually `UPDATE`** a row in the `ItemTable`, which would normally be done in just one query:

```
query = \
    """
    UPDATE ItemTable
    SET Col = ?, ColOther = ?
    WHERE ID = 100;
    """
cursor.execute(query, 'new', 'newother')
```

Instead of just doing the `UPDATE` like above, I would like to do these things for `ItemTable`:

- **Automatically `UPDATE`** the old row to have `Latest = 0`
- `INSERT` the row with the updated values, and `Latest = 1` (Let's say this row gets the `ID` 250)

Then for the `ProductTable`:

- **Automatically `UPDATE`** the old linking row in the ProductTable to have `Latest = 0`
- And **automatically `INSERT`** the same row with the new `ItemID` and `Latest = 1`

This automatic `INSERT` and `UPDATE` would preferably happen with just a pure SQL query (perhaps using `OUTPUT`, but I'm not familiar with that), alternatively it could be implemented with some Python code. How would I go about doing this?

The wanted end result:

```sql
ItemTable:

ID    Col      ColOther     Latest    Time
100   'old'    'oldother'   0         <Autogenerated timestamp>
250   'new'    'newother'   1         <Autogenerated timestamp>


ProductTable:

ID    ItemID   Value   ValueOther   Latest   Time
12    100      'foo'   'bar'        0        <Autogenerated timestamp>
110   250      'foo'   'bar'        1        <Autogenerated timestamp>
```

Comment: You can write Trigger for this on insertion

Comment: [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will be useful.

Comment: Are you able to target the rows by ID? In that case, you simply do `UPDATE table SET Latest=0 WHERE ID=12` and `INSERT table SET ItemID=250, Value='foo', ValueOther='bar', Latest=1`. This is also assuming that the column ID is auto incremented. If you have another language complimenting the SQL, providing that would be very helpful also.

Comment: I can follow your logic if ProductTable will only ever contain information about one product, otherwise I don't see how to identify which ProductTable row should be copied. Please [edit] your question to flesh out your example.

Comment: @GordThompson I've edited my question quite a bit, it should be a lot clearer now. Please check it out :)

Comment: editing your question much makes it a different question.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yeah, I possibly changed it a bit too much in the process of improving it, but it won't change anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a modern version of SQL Server (i.e. >= SQL Server 2016 SP1)

Have you considered using a **Temporal Table** for this?
You can read more about at [Microsofts BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017)

It is a very smart method for tracking changes to tables. It performs well, but altering the table structure is a bit of work.

Comment: I've never heard of these :O They seem **really really nice**, but I'm unfortunately running SQL Server 2008 SP1, and don't have any control about changing that...

Comment: @ruohola; End-of-life is near: July 8, 2019  https://community.connection.com/windows-sql-server-2008-2008-r2-end-life-coming-soon-now/
This could be a good argument for upgrading...

Comment: I'm sure my company will update in time, but I have 0 control over when that happens or to what version we'll update.

Comment: I know the feeling (of despair). But good arguments usually help persuade managers.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging words :D I'll do my best.

Comment: @ruohola; I know the feeling (like an extra Christmas gift). Don't forget to add SP and CUs.

Answer (score 6):

Use [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this:

I would not use triggers for this, to much activity in the trigger would result in undesired things happening when other changes occur. Instead I am using a stored procedure

I rewrote my answer after the question was changed:

```sql
-- create test tables and test data
CREATE table item
(ID int identity, 
Col varchar(99), 
ColOther varchar(99),
Latest bit default 1,
Time datetime default getdate())

INSERT item(col, colother) 
values('old','oldother')

CREATE table product
(ID int identity,
ItemID int,
[Value] varchar(20),
ValueOther varchar(20),
Latest bit default 1,
Time datetime default getdate())

INSERT product(itemid, [value], valueother)
values(1, 'foo', 'bar')

go
-- create procedure
CREATE procedure p_insert
(
  @id int,
  @col varchar(99),
  @colOther varchar(99)
)
as
BEGIN tran t
DECLARE @out table(IDold int, IDnew int)
INSERT item(col, colother, Latest)
OUTPUT @id, inserted.id INTO @out
SELECT @col, @colother, 1
FROM item
WHERE 
  id = @id
  and latest = 1

UPDATE i
SET Latest=0
FROM item i
JOIN @out o 
ON o.IDold = i.id
and i.Latest=1

DECLARE @p table
(itemid int,
[value] varchar(20),
valueother varchar(20))

UPDATE p
SET Latest=0
OUTPUT o.IDnew, deleted.[value],deleted.[valueother] 
INTO @p
FROM product p
JOIN @out o
ON p.ItemID = o.IDold
WHERE p.Latest=1

INSERT product(itemid, [value], valueother,  Latest)
SELECT itemid, value, valueother, 1
FROM @p
commit tran t
```

To test this:

```
exec p_insert 1, 'a','b'
```

Note this will only work if you try to update the existing row where Latest=1.

Comment: I like `OUTPUT`, but I find its requirement of no triggers on dml'ed and into'd tables restricting.

Comment: When using this with my actual tables I just get `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Latest', table 'dbo.ItemTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`. I had to change both of the `INSERT` statements to also insert the value `1` to column `Latest`.

Comment: This is a nice solution, and I appreciate your answer a lot, but I'll have to go with @AliAl-Mosawi extremely clean solution.

Comment: @ruohola instead of changing the query, you could have considered modifing the default value of the columns. I imagine upon inserting a new row, you would want the Latest to be 1 unless otherwise specified

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes that could've been a valid option also. But adding the few `Latest` inserts there wasn't the reason I didn't accept this. Biggest reason why I went with the other answer was that it was just nicer since it works with normal `UPDATE` statements and that suits my use case little bit better.

Comment: True that answer handles the logging directly, My answer will only make the logging when using the procedure. It all depends of your requirements. If you wanted to add the person doing the change, my answer would have been easier to modify to handle this

Answer (score 5):

The below trigger will do what you want:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ItemTable_OnUpdate
ON ItemTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newId int, @oldId int


    INSERT INTO ItemTable(Col, ColOther, Latest)
    SELECT Col, ColOther, 1 FROM INSERTED

    --get old and new ids
    SELECT @newId=@@IDENTITY, @oldId=ID FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE ItemTable SET Latest=0 WHERE ID=@oldId


    --updating ProductTable
    INSERT INTO ProductTable (ItemID, [Value], ValueOther, Latest)
    SELECT @newId, [Value], ValueOther, 1 FROM ProductTable WHERE ItemID=@oldId


    UPDATE ProductTable SET Latest=0 WHERE ItemID=@oldId
END;
```

After creating the trigger any update will insert new record in `ItemTable`, update the prev. with `Latest = 0`, and update the child table as per your req.

The below is my output after the update below:

```sql
UPDATE ItemTable SET col='new', ColOther='newother' WHERE ID=12;
```

ItemTable:

```sql
ID  Col   ColOther  Latest  Time
12  old   oldother  0       0x00000000000007F0
13  new   newother  1       0x00000000000007EF
```

ProductTable:

```sql
ID  ItemID  Value   ValueOther  Latest  Time
18  12      foo     bar         0       0x00000000000007F2
19  13      foo     bar         1       0x00000000000007F1
```

For multiple row updates we can use the below trigger, as the above was designed as reference for the update that the requester specified (one row). I believe the below will handle multiple row updates. please try it.

```
create TRIGGER ItemTable_OnUpdate
ON ItemTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @s table( IdNew int,IdOld int)


MERGE INTO ItemTable AS dest
USING INSERTED AS ins ON 1=0   -- always false
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET          -- happens for every row, because 1 is never 0
        THEN 
            INSERT (Col, ColOther, Latest)
                     VALUES (Col, ColOther, Latest)
            OUTPUT inserted.ID, ins.ID INTO @s (IdNew, IdOld);


UPDATE ItemTable SET Latest=0 WHERE ID in (select IdOld from @s)


    --updating ProductTable
    INSERT INTO ProductTable (ItemID, [Value], ValueOther, Latest)
    SELECT s.IdNew, pt.[Value], pt.ValueOther, 1 FROM @s s
        inner join ProductTable pt on pt.ItemID=s.IdOld


    UPDATE ProductTable SET Latest=0 WHERE ItemID in (select IdOld from @s)
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it's an extremely clean solution! Enjoy the bounty :)